# What is an OH LED?

Tags: motherboard, case, led

My SuperMicro case has an led labeled `OH LED`. It's in the bundle of wires with the other LED lights and switches. What does that stand for and go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "OH LED" corresponds to Overheat -- in the event your mother board has one. Find the mention of this in [the SuperMicro manual here.](http://www.orbitmicro.com/download/resources/MBD-X7DGU-Manual.pdf)

> OH LED (JOH1) Overheat LED Indicator